# How to get 2 words to cross at intersecting characters. (One vertically and the other horizontally)

Tags: java, for-loop, printing, crossword

I'm working on a homework assignment for school, the assignment states "get two words as input and prints one vertically and one horizontally so that they intersect".

An Example of this:

```
vertical: coffee
horizontal: suffering
  c
  o
suffering
  f
  e
  e
```

When I enter in coffee and suffering I get this as an output:

```
vertical: coffee
horizontal: suffering
   c
   o
suffering
   f
   f
   e
   e
```

My code is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("vertical: ");
    String vertical = kb.next().toLowerCase();

    System.out.print("horizontal: ");
    String horizontal = kb.next().toLowerCase();

    boolean indexed = true;
    int indexOf = 0;
    StringBuilder spaces = new StringBuilder();

    while (indexed) {
      for (int i = 1; i <= vertical.length()-1; i++) {
        String found = vertical.substring(i - 1, i);
        spaces.append(" ");
        if (horizontal.contains(found)) {
          indexOf = i;
          indexed = false;
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= vertical.length(); i++) {
      if (i == indexOf) {
        System.out.println(horizontal);
      }
      System.out.println(spaces + vertical.substring(i - 1, i));
    }
  }
```

Comment: You have several problems.  The first is that you print both strings when the i == indexOf.  The second one is more subtle.  What happens when the vertical word is shorter than the horizontal word?  The horizontal word never gets printed if the index is too far to the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some pointers.

1. Use indexOf to find the intersection point.
2. The index of horizontal word is how far to indent the vertical characters.
   Once the index is found, the spacing is easily obtained by doing something like the following:

```java
     spaces = "                        ".substring(0,indexOf);
```

3. The index of the vertical word is at what point to print the horizontal word
   and NOT the vertical character.
4. Remember to handle the special case when no character is in common.
5. You don't need a nested while and for loop.  One or the other is all that is needed.

Comment: Thank you for your help. What would be the ideal way of going about printing the horizontal word in the correct location instead of relying on the vertical characters being in the right location?

Comment: Print the vertical characters as you normally would with the indenting and a character.  When indexOf = the proper position, print the horizontal word but NOT the vertical character.